# How to verify if a value in HashMap exist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator, hashmap

I have the following `HashMap` where the `key` is a `String` and the `value` is represented by an `ArrayList`:

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> productsMap = AsyncUpload.getFoodMap();
```

I also have another `ArrayList<String> foods` implemented in my application.

My question is, What would be the best way to find out if my `HashMap` contains a Specific `String` from my second `ArrayList`?

I have tried without success:

```
Iterator<String> keySetIterator = productsMap.keySet().iterator();
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> valueSetIterator = productsMap.values().iterator();

    while(keySetIterator.hasNext() && valueSetIterator.hasNext()){
        String key = keySetIterator.next();
        if(mArrayList.contains(key)){
            System.out.println("Yes! its a " + key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your `key` value supposed to be the specific string?

Comment: Yes. It should be a specific String.

Comment: 'Without success' s not a problem description.

Comment: alternative way without loops productsMap.toString().contains(key) . Of course there can be some problems like, key can be part of some different value or map key and this is not for big maps. Anyway it's just an option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not:

```
// fast-enumerating map's values
for (ArrayList<String> value: productsMap.values()) {
    // using ArrayList#contains
    System.out.println(value.contains("myString"));
}
```

And if you have to iterate over the whole `ArrayList<String>`, instead of looking for one specific value only:

```
// fast-enumerating food's values ("food" is an ArrayList<String>)
for (String item: foods) {
    // fast-enumerating map's values
    for (ArrayList<String> value: productsMap.values()) {
        // using ArrayList#contains
        System.out.println(value.contains(item));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Past time I updated this with some Java 8 idioms.

The Java 8 streams API allows a more declarative (and arguably elegant) way of handling these types of iteration.

For instance, here's a (slightly too verbose) way to achieve the same:

```
// iterate foods 
foods
    .stream()
    // matches any occurrence of...
    .anyMatch(
        // ... any list matching any occurrence of...
        (s) -> productsMap.values().stream().anyMatch(
            // ... the list containing the iterated item from foods
            (l) -> l.contains(s)
        )
    )
```

... and here's a simpler way to achieve the same, initially iterating the `productsMap` values instead of the contents of `foods`:

```
// iterate productsMap values
productsMap
    .values()
    .stream()
    // flattening to all list elements
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    // matching any occurrence of...
    .anyMatch(
        // ... an element contained in foods
        (s) -> foods.contains(s)
    )
```

Comment: I have some additional doubt in the if "myString" values not known completely ,I know only just myStri .How to verify that or find the complete value by using contains some charactes as "myStri". Could you help me please.@Mena.or anyone

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `containsKey()` method. To do this, you simply get the hashMap you want the key out of, then use the `containsKey` method, which will return a `boolean` value if it does. This will search the whole hashMap without having to iterate over each item. If you do have the key, then you can simply retrieve the value.

It might look something like:

```
if(productsMap.values().containsKey("myKey"))
{
    // do something if hashMap has key
}
```

Here is the link to [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

From the Android docs:

> public boolean containsKey (Object key) Added in API level 1
>
> Returns whether this map contains the specified key. Parameters key
>     the key to search for. Returns
>
> ```
> true if this map contains the specified key, false otherwise.
> ```

Comment: why does it named containsKey rather than containsValue though? If the purpose is to know whether it contain value or not.

Comment: why not use `productsMap.containsValue("myKey")`

Comment: @aldok There is nothing in your question about looking in the values.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
public boolean anyKeyInMap(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> productsMap, List<String> keys) {
    Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>(keys);

    for (ArrayList<String> strings : productsMap.values()) {
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (keySet.contains(string)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hashMap.containsValue("your value");
```

Will check if the HashMap contains the value

Comment: @EJP https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Iterator<String> keySetIterator = productsMap.keySet().iterator();
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> valueSetIterator = productsMap.values().iterator();

    while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
        String key = keySetIterator.next();
        if(valueSetIterator.next().contains(key)){    // corrected here
            System.out.println("Yes! its a " + key);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Java 8 way of doing it, you could do something like this:

```
    private static boolean containsValue(final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map, final String value){
    return map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.contains(value)).findFirst().orElse(null) != null;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
    private static boolean containsValue(final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map, final String value){
    return map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.contains(value)).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

Both should produce pretty much the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample method that tests for both scenarios. Searching for items in map's keys and also search for items in the lists of each map entry:

```
private static void testMapSearch(){

    final ArrayList<String> fruitsList = new ArrayList<String>();        
    fruitsList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Grapes"));

    final ArrayList<String> veggiesList = new ArrayList<String>();        
    veggiesList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Potato", "Squash", "Beans"));

    final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> productsMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    productsMap.put("fruits", fruitsList);
    productsMap.put("veggies", veggiesList);

    final ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();        
    foodList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Squash", "fruits"));

    // Check if items from foodList exist in the keyset of productsMap

    for(String item : foodList){
        if(productsMap.containsKey(item)){
            System.out.println("productsMap contains a key named " + item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("productsMap doesn't contain a key named " + item);
        }
    }

    // Check if items from foodList exits in productsMap's values

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : productsMap.entrySet()){

        System.out.println("\nSearching on list values for key " + entry.getKey() + "..");

        for(String item : foodList){
            if(entry.getValue().contains(item)){
                System.out.println("productMap's list under key " + entry.getKey() + " contains item " + item);
            } else {
                System.out.println("productMap's list under key " + entry.getKey() + " doesn't contain item " + item);
            }
        }      
    } 
}
```

Here's the result:

> productsMap doesn't contain a key named Apple
>
> productsMap doesn't contain a key named Squash
>
> productsMap contains a key named fruits
>
> Searching on list values for key fruits..
>
> productMap's list under key fruits contains item Apple
>
> productMap's list under key fruits doesn't contain item Squash
>
> productMap's list under key fruits doesn't contain item fruits
>
> Searching on list values for key veggies..
>
> productMap's list under key veggies doesn't contain item Apple
>
> productMap's list under key veggies contains item Squash
>
> productMap's list under key veggies doesn't contain item fruits