# Java - Check if value in ArrayList nested in HashMap exists

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, exists

I have various `ArrayList`s nested in one `HashMap`.

How can I check if my array list nested in the hashmap exists?

```
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> transactionMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

public static void initializeLists() {
    transactionMap.put(7, new ArrayList<Integer> (Arrays.asList(1050, 1125)));
    transactionMap.put(305, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1125)));
    transactionMap.put(1125, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(250, 252, 251)));
    transactionMap.put(1050, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(251, 252)));
    transactionMap.put(1124, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(250)));
    transactionMap.put(1049, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(251, 252)));
}
```

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404084/find-if-a-value-exists-in-arraylist/here) describes how to check directly in an `Array
List` using `#contains(Object)`, which does not fit for `HashMap`.

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389135/how-to-verify-if-a-value-in-hashmap-exist/here) is close but it would mean I would have to give a name to all my lists (and there could be many). I would like to avoid having to nest a map inside a map if possible unless needed.
Does anyone have any points to the best solution?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a ``Map<Integer, int[]>`` instead? And btw. your example isn't valid java code.

Comment: If you are able to use Guava, you can use a Multimap, specifically an [ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html), and then just use [`multimap.containsValue`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object)). Otherwise, you'd need to iterate through all values, calling `contains` on each until you find one.

Comment: use containsValue method

Comment: These lists can be simplified as new `Arrays.<Integer> asList(...)`

Comment: @LanceJava That's not the same. If you don't copy the list into a new array list, you can't make structural modifications to the list.

Comment: How do you calculate the `key` value in your `transactionMap`, is it transaction ID ?

Comment: @AndyTurner you are correct. I'm assuming the map is not mutated after initialization.

Comment: @MaxZoom It is not a calculated, it is just a transaction ID.

Comment: @Tommy This returns a collection of values, I do not believe it checks for a particular value (I tried...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is "how do I check if a specific list is a value in the map" then you can do it as follows:

```
if (transactionMap.containsValue(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)) {
    ...
}
```

If your question is "how do I check if a specific integer appears somewhere in a list as a value in the map" then you can do the following (using Java 8):

```
if (transactionMap.values().stream().anyMatch(l -> l.contains(17)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Each key in my map has a different ArrayList :/ I need to be able to deep dive into the arraylist of the key in the Map.

Comment: @Aurax22 No actually your key is a simple integer - not a list. The values are lists.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean 'deep dive into the arraylist of the values in the map'. I've added a solution for that to my answer.

Comment: Using your last tip, it works perfectly, thanks a lot. I'll try and be more specific on my questions next time also! I am a beginner but this seems like a "fancy" way to do it, I am surprised there is no simple way (unless the simple way was to use a nested map).